# Android 5.0 Overview screen displays two snapshots when any dialog is opened

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-dialog

I have some dialog opened in my app. Now, when I tap *Overview* button(square button) the Overview screen displays two snapshots of the app(one above another). 
On tapping Suspend button (circle button), it works fine and I could see only one snapshot.
 Can anyone tell me why am I seeing this anomalous behavior and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Please post you question clearly what are those snapshots, circle and square buttons?

Comment: I could not post the snapshots of the app. The circle and square buttons are the navigation bar buttons: Pause button and Overview button. Also, the snapshots here means the tasks visible in the Overview screen( also referred to as the recents screen, recent task list, or recent apps).